# How to match {{param}} in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, escaping, handlebars.js

I thought about:

```
gsed -n -e 's/{{\(.+\)}}/&/p' file
gsed -n -e 's/{{\(.+\)}}/\&/p' file
gsed -n -e 's/{{\(.+\)}}/\1/p' file
...
gsed -n -e 's/{{(.+)}}/\&/p' file
gsed -n -e 's/{{\([^{}]+\)}}/\&/p' file
gsed -n -e 's/{{([^{}]+)}}/\&/p' file
...
```

But they doesn't match anything (empty output).

I have a handlebars template and would like to extract all parameters I need to pass to the template.

How could the pattern and sed command look like to match and extract the content of double curly brackets?

So I would like:

from:

```
<div class="{{some.class}}">
 <img src"{{img.url}}">
</div>
```

get:

```
some.class
img.url
```

## Update:

```
gsed -n 's/^.*{{\([^{}]+\)}}.*$/\1/p' file
```

doesn't work

Comment: doesnt doing it in 2 pieces work? i.e. `sed 's/^.*{{//;s/}}.*$/' file` Good luck.

Comment: I'm getting `gsed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated 's' command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '\{\{\K[^}]*' file
some.class
img.url
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '{{|}}' 'NF>1{print $2}' file
some.class
img.url
```

To print all matches using awk:

```
awk -F '{{|}}' 'NF>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}'
```

Comment: what are the options `grep -oP` for the OSX version of grep? `awk` version worked well!

Comment: `grep --version -> grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. Yep, as I said awk version worked well! Thank you!

Comment: What about `perl -ne '/{{([^}]*)}}/ and print "$1\n"' file`

Comment: Oh ok mine is `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` on OSX

Comment: :) yep, I thought the `gnu` version would causing the differences

Comment: For the awk version, in case there's more than one per line, you could print all even-numbered fields.

Comment: you mean a `for loop over $@` and `print $1` or similar? How it would look like? I have some cases with multiple `{{...}}` per line, and I would like to print them all in one column, not sequentially (e.g. using `print $2, $3, $4 ...`)

Comment: @static: That would be: **`awk -F '{{|}}' 'NF>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' file`**

Answer (score 1):

You must escape opening curly brackets:

```
echo '<div class="{{truc}}" {{bidule}}>' | sed -r 's/\{\{([^}]+)}}/\1/g'
```

Comment: gettig error: `gsed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '-' ...`. Without `-e` no output at all.

Comment: hm, the updated variant works fine. I see, it substitutes, not extracts the matched word.